# Highcharts (specifically mapChart) how do I load using csvURL in data?

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

Highcharts (specifically `mapChart`) how do I load from csv?

I started with the basic example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/color-axis

... which is based on `.getJSON()` & modified it to match similar `chart` or `stockChart` working examples I have with csv...

For instance, I tried this simple replacement:

```
series: [{
    //... demo code ...

    //data: data,

    data: {
        csvURL: 'http://localhost/testData.csv',
        enablePolling: false
    },

    //... demo code ...
```

... which works for other chart types (line, bar, etc.) but doesn't work for `mapChart`?  When I try, I get the following error:

[image: highmaps.src.js:54109:20 === Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: c.forEach is not a function]
highmaps.src.js:54109:20 === Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: c.forEach is not a function

For reference, testData.csv, contains the following:

```
code,value,label
ND,13,42
SD,42,69
```

... and I tried this as well, just in case:

```
"code","value","label"
"ND",13,"Thirteen"
"SD",42,"FortyTwo"
```

I've looked in the documentation, but can't find any special "callout" for `mapChart`, stating this functionality doesn't work for `mapChart`:

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/data.csvURL

I want to use `data.csvURL` because then it matches all my other code flows for the other types of charts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jabaa When you're quickly touch typing them (space inbetween), you don't see the 'descriptions' as they just auto-apply.  So I didn't know they had a DO NOT USE tag...  they should really just program the site so that when you submit, it errors & won't let you until you remove it (or at least double check it) if they want to prevent it.  But I did edit & remove it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Have you checked this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/rich-info/)? It show how to load data from csv to highmaps.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus thanks for the suggestion...  I was able to parse/convert my csv to an object & have it work; but due to other project constraints, I wanted to use the `csvURL` functionality...  in my answer below; I have it working, but it involved a different approach to the example provided by highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't understand why:

```
series:           ...
    data:         ...
        csvURL:   ...
```

...  doesn't work, the following will work:

```
(async () => {

    const topology = await fetch(
        'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.topo.json'
    ).then(response => response.json());

    // Instantiate the map
    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

        chart: {
            map: topology,
            borderWidth: 1
        },

        data: {
            //csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
            csvURL: 'http://localhost/testData.csv',
            seriesMapping: [{
                code: 0,
                value: 1,
                label: 2
            }]
        },

        title: {
            text: 'US population density (/km²)'
        },

        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 600,
            sourceHeight: 500
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 1,
            type: 'logarithmic',
            minColor: '#EEEEFF',
            maxColor: '#000022',
            stops: [
                [0, '#EFEFFF'],
                [0.67, '#4444FF'],
                [1, '#000022']
            ]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 1000
                },
                joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    format: '{point.code}'
                },
                name: 'Population density',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.value}/km²'
                }
            }
        }
    });

})();
```

Though I'd still love to understand why it doesn't work in my original quesiton.?.